Chrome < 88 has issues recognizing DST with Day.js
My company is thinking about introducing day.js to handle DST. This works well on modern browsers, but on browsers older than Chrome 88 it will not work. I have this little app to test Day.js:
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import utc from 'dayjs/plugin/utc';
import timezone from 'dayjs/plugin/timezone';

dayjs.extend(utc);
dayjs.extend(timezone);

const defaultTimezone = "Africa/Cairo";

const events = [
  { date: '2024-04-20', time: '20:00', description: 'Event 1', timezone: defaultTimezone },
  { date: '2024-04-30', time: '20:00', description: 'Event 2', timezone: defaultTimezone },
  { date: '2024-06-05', time: '20:00', description: 'Event 3', timezone: defaultTimezone },
  { date: '2024-09-20', time: '20:00', description: 'Event 4', timezone: defaultTimezone },
  { date: '2024-10-20', time: '20:00', description: 'Event 5', timezone: defaultTimezone },
  { date: '2024-11-20', time: '20:00', description: 'Event 6', timezone: defaultTimezone },
];

function App() {
  const [formattedEvents, setFormattedEvents] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const formattedEvents = events.map(event => {
      const cairoDateTime = dayjs.tz(`${event.date}T${event.time}`, event.timezone);
      const berlinDateTime = cairoDateTime.clone().tz('Europe/Berlin');
      
      const formattedCairoDateTime = cairoDateTime.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
      const formattedBerlinDateTime = berlinDateTime.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');

      return {
        ...event,
        cairoDateTime: formattedCairoDateTime,
        berlinDateTime: formattedBerlinDateTime
      };
    });
    setFormattedEvents(formattedEvents);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h2>Events</h2>
        <ul>
          {formattedEvents.map((event, index) => (
            <li key={index}>
              {event.description}: 
              <ul>
                <li>Cairo Time: {event.cairoDateTime} ({event.timezone})</li>
                <li>Berlin Time: {event.berlinDateTime} (Europe/Berlin)</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

which on modern browsers works as expected:
Events
Event 1:
Cairo Time: 2024-04-20 20:00:00 (Africa/Cairo)
Berlin Time: 2024-04-20 20:00:00 (Europe/Berlin)
Event 2:
Cairo Time: 2024-04-30 20:00:00 (Africa/Cairo)
Berlin Time: 2024-04-30 19:00:00 (Europe/Berlin)
Event 3:
Cairo Time: 2024-06-05 20:00:00 (Africa/Cairo)
Berlin Time: 2024-06-05 19:00:00 (Europe/Berlin)
Event 4:
Cairo Time: 2024-09-20 20:00:00 (Africa/Cairo)
Berlin Time: 2024-09-20 19:00:00 (Europe/Berlin)
Event 5:
Cairo Time: 2024-10-20 20:00:00 (Africa/Cairo)
Berlin Time: 2024-10-20 19:00:00 (Europe/Berlin)
Event 6:
Cairo Time: 2024-11-20 20:00:00 (Africa/Cairo)
Berlin Time: 2024-11-20 19:00:00 (Europe/Berlin)

But for the old browser it will produce this output:
Events
Event 1:
Cairo Time: 2024-04-20 20:00:00 (Africa/Cairo)
Berlin Time: 2024-04-20 20:00:00 (Europe/Berlin)
Event 2:
Cairo Time: 2024-04-30 20:00:00 (Africa/Cairo)
Berlin Time: 2024-04-30 20:00:00 (Europe/Berlin)
Event 3:
Cairo Time: 2024-06-05 20:00:00 (Africa/Cairo)
Berlin Time: 2024-06-05 20:00:00 (Europe/Berlin)
Event 4:
Cairo Time: 2024-09-20 20:00:00 (Africa/Cairo)
Berlin Time: 2024-09-20 20:00:00 (Europe/Berlin)
Event 5:
Cairo Time: 2024-10-20 20:00:00 (Africa/Cairo)
Berlin Time: 2024-10-20 20:00:00 (Europe/Berlin)
Event 6:
Cairo Time: 2024-11-20 20:00:00 (Africa/Cairo)
Berlin Time: 2024-11-20 19:00:00 (Europe/Berlin)

As you can see, the DST is not correctly displayed. Does anyone have any idea how this could be fixed?

Sounds like outdated time zone data. Do your users really run such old Google Chrome?

Yes they run this code on old chromeboxes which still use very old versions of Google Chrome
